# What are Starred repositories in Github?

Tags: github, repository

What are Starred repositories in Github? - (Not watched repos).

This is a **new** Github features, and they didn't explain it as well...

Comment: Don't see why this should be closed as it's about typical developer tools and not general software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Noticed, how the notifications of the watched repos polluted your news feed? It's separated now into "starred", that is just a flag and "watch". Later one will go into your news feed, first one will not.

You can find a very [detailed explanation in Githubs blog](https://github.com/blog/1204-notifications-stars)

Comment: Finally they changed the "watch" feature. It was never used as it was meant to be.

Comment: Must say, that I don't really understood, what it was meant to be. I used it as a kind of bookmark and I was often totally annoyed of the noise within my feed. But creating browser bookmarks, or even forks werent real options too. So I'm happy, that I can "reanimate" the feed again :)

Comment: Agree. It was also used to kind of "thumbs up" the repositories.

Comment: They eventually added this page: 
https://help.github.com/articles/about-stars/
"Starring a repository allows you to keep track of projects that you find interesting, even if you aren't associated with the project."  So it's like an official bookmark / thumbs-up indicator.